# unrecognised exception in windows C++ code

Tags: visual-c++

We have a number of sections of code in the format:

```
try
{
  // code
}
catch(std::exception &e)
{
  // log exception
}
catch(...)
{
  // log unknown exception.
}
```

Every so often, the unknown exception code triggers, and logs an unknown exception.

I always thought that all exceptions were meant to derive from std::exception, and thus catching std::exception would catch all exceptions.

1. Is there some other exception that I should be catching?
2. If my code ends up in the unknown exception handler, is there any way that I can find out what exception was actually caught?

**edit**

We managed to locate the cause of the problem- despite saying that they had, the customer had not installed .NET 3.5, which our code depends on, and the system fell over when trying to use the XML parser.

Comment: What is this "non-user exception" of which you speak? I'm not familiar with the term. The easiest way to figure out the unknown exception is to **not** have a `catch(...)` handler. Allow the exception to wind up in the debugger.

Comment: What I meant was any exception thrown by things like the C++ run-time library, etc. I.e, stuff that I haven't written

Comment: The C++ run-time library does throw exceptions derived from `std::exception`. So your unknown exception is not one of those. Most likely, you have a straight-out access violation, which MSVC catches in `catch(...)` clause [under some circumstances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx). Basically, there's a bug in your program that you should find and fix; having a `catch(...)` clause makes this more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some other exception that I should be catching?

This depends on your code. Libraries you call can throw exceptions not derived from std::exception, examples are MFC's `CException` or Microsoft's `_com_error`. Also, an access violation might be catched by `catch(...)`, which is the reason why I would not use `catch(...)` in my code - it's just to broad for me.

> 2.If my code ends up in the unknown exception handler, is there any way that I can find out what exception was actually caught?

You can run your code in the debugger and configure the debugger to break your program when the exception is thrown (first chance). Then you know exactly which line of code triggers the exception and should be able to see what exactly is thrown.

Comment: The error is one of those occasional, once every 6 months, only on customer site type exceptions, so running it under the debugger is not really possible.

Comment: I'ld guess it is an access violation. In that case I would remove the `catch(...)` and ask the customer to activate DrWatson. This will give you a crash dump when the access violation occurs and you can dig deeper (if you give the customer a version with debug info, e.g. as PDB file and if you keep the intermediate files to better track down the assembler code).